# Block element was pushed down to next row

Tags: css, html

I have 4 boxes wrapped in a main box. The first two boxes were originally on the same row. Somehow something may have been deleted and now box 2 (I labeled it "myissue" in the code below) was pushed down and box 3 and 4 are still fine, just pushed further down the page to allow space for box 2.

Box 1 is "slideshow" which is fine
Box 2 is "myissue" which should be to the right of "slideshow"

Box 3 is "browsebox" which was pushed down
Box 4 is "foo-wrap" which was pushed down

The page is fine, it just looks like the page is seeing a br tag between slideshow and myissue.

```
<div id="homepage">
<div id="slideshow-wrap" class="left">
    <script>
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#slideshow').vslide({
        speed: 5000
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>

<div id="slideshow">
  <a href="http://s.htm" alt="" class="slide" style="display: none;"></a>
  <a href="http://s.htm"><img src="/.jpg" alt="" class="slide" style="display: none;">       </a>
  <a href="http://s.htm"><img src="/.jpg" alt="" class="slide currentPic"   style="display: block;"></a>
  <a href="https://s.asp?"><img src="/.jpg" alt="" class="slide" style="display: none;"></a>
  <a href="http://s.htm"><img src="/.jpg" alt="" class="slide" style="display: none;"></a>

  <div id="btns_wrap">
    <a class="back_btn" href="#">&lt;</a><!--LEFT ARROW-->
    <div id="btns">
      <a class="" href="#">1</a>
      <a href="#" class="">2</a>
      <a href="#" class="selected">3</a>
      <a href="#" class="">4</a>
      <a href="#" class="">5</a>
    </div>
    <a class="forward_btn" href="#">&gt;</a><!--RIGHT ARROW-->
  </div>


</div> <!-- #slideshow -->
    <div id="myissue" class="left">
        <div id="myissue-title">
            Div with issue
        </div>
        <div id="myissue-box">
                        <div class="myissue-entry">abc.</div>
                        <div class="myissue-entry"><br></div>
                        <div class="myissue-entry">123.</div>
            <div class="myissue-entry"><br></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>

    <div id="browse-box">
        <div id="browse-box-title">Browse Stuff</div>

        <div class="b-box b1 transition left">
            <a href="http://s.htm"><img src="/.jpg" alt="foo"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="b-box b2 left">
<a class="b-box-link transition" href="http://.htm">
                <div class="b-box-link-top">
                    <div class="left">
                        foo &amp; bar
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <img src="/.png" alt="Arrow">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="b-box-link-bottom">
                    Hello World! 
                </div>
            </a>

        </div>

        <div class="b-box b3 left">
            <a class="b-box-link transition" href="http://.htm">
                <div class="b-box-link-top">
                    <div class="left">
                        Things
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <img src="/.png" alt="Arrow">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="b-box-link-bottom">
                    More things! 
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="clear">
        </div>

        <div class="b-box b4 left">
            <a class="b-box-link transition" href="http://.htm">
                <div class="b-box-link-top">
                    <div class="left">
                        Foo
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <img src="/.png" alt="Arrow">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="b-box-link-bottom">
                    Hello!
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="b-box b5 left">
            <a class="b-box-link transition" href="http://.htm">
                <div class="b-box-link-top">
                    <div class="left">
                        Hello
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <img src="/.png" alt="Arrow">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="b-box-link-bottom">
                    Hello!
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="b-box b6 transition left">
            <a href="/.asp"><img src="/.jpg" alt="abc"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<div id="foo-wrap">
        <div id="foo-title">Foo</div>
        <div id="fooslider">&nbsp;</div>    
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @C B Please update question; provide some CSS too. Further, a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) couldn't hurt either !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a missing closing div above it.